# Multiple large GOOGLEFINANCE formulas make spreadsheet unresponsive

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-performance

## Problem

In Google Sheets I have huge GOOGLEFINANCE formulas that return accurate results however the sheet is often unresponsive, and can take a few hours to recalculate when reloaded.

Is there a way to shorten the calculation and make the page load faster?

## Current Formula

Accurately performs the calculation for a single stock over a single 52-week period:

```
=(((((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 2, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 2, 1))))/((((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 2, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 2, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 3, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 3, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 4, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 4, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 5, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 5, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 6, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 6, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 7, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 7, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 8, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 8, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 9, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 9, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 10, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 10, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 11, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 11, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 12, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 12, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 13, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 13, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 14, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 14, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 15, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 15, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 16, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 16, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 17, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 17, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 18, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 18, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 19, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 19, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 20, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 20, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 21, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 21, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 22, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 22, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 23, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 23, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 24, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 24, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 25, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 25, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 26, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 26, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 27, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 27, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 28, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 28, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 29, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 29, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 30, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 30, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 31, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 31, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 32, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 32, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 33, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 33, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 34, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 34, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 35, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 35, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 36, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 36, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 37, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 37, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 38, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 38, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 39, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 39, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 40, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 40, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 41, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 41, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 42, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 42, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 43, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 43, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 44, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 44, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 45, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 45, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 46, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 46, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 47, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 47, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 48, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 48, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 49, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 49, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 50, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 50, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 51, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 51, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 52, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 52, 1)))+((INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("NSE:"&$A3, "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 53, 1))/(INDEX(QUERY(GoogleFinance("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50", "price", TODAY()-560, TODAY(), "weekly"), "select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 100"), 53, 1))))/52)-1)*10)
```

## Overview

1. Column A contains roughly 2,000 NSE-listed stocks.
2. For each stock, I need to return a comparison of its weekly pricing over 52 weeks to the [NIFTY_50](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/NIFTY_50:INDEXNSE) benchmark index's pricing for the same period.
3. For each stock, I would like to perform the calculation 8 times, once in each of Columns G through N with the only difference being that each calculation's 52-week period is offset 1 week in the past from the previous column's:

   - Column G: week   0 through Week -51
   - Column H: week -1 through week -52
     <sub>. . . *continues*</sub>
   - Column N: week -7 through week -58
4. Visualizing the Calculation:

   ```
   =((cur-wk)/AVERAGE(all-wks)-1)*10
   ```

   - **`cur-wk`**
     A single value calculated from the current week's stock price divided by the current week's benchmark index price.
   - **`all-wks`**
     A 1x52 array of values returned by calculating, for each of the 52 weeks in the period, that week's stock price divided by that week's benchmark index price.

[Link to editable spreadsheet showing formula and required results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gK_gRSHaAygcI1BR9TcTyvKG-jlcdJL9B8Kevfws9K4/edit#gid=0)

## Cross-Posted

- [Excel Forums](https://www.excelforum.com/for-other-platforms-mac-google-docs-mobile-os-etc/1413721-huge-calculations-in-a-cell-google-sheets-not-loading.html#post5882013)
- [Google Support](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/239659672/huge-calculations-google-sheets-not-loading) (Successfully answered)

Comment: FYI, your original wasn't accurate because it assumed 52 weeks of data and 8% of your stocks don't have 52 weeks of history, and 9% don't have 59 weeks (required to offset the 52-week period back 7 weeks).  Use AVERAGE to avoid this error.  ie. `AVERAGE(SEQUENCE(52,1,1,0))=1` *and* `SUM(SEQUENCE(52,1,1,0))/52=1` *and* `AVERAGE(SEQUENCE(40,1,1,0))=1`  ***but*** `SUM(SEQUENCE(40,1,1,0))/52<>1` See [Calculate weeks of available data per stock](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IC1S3UsWnMNFLpfPIFemogBA4l_aiT0KGBLC6ourRtM/edit#gid=1025773672) in the demo sheet.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula for 8 Weeks

- Place in `G2` to calculate `G2:N`

```
=LET(range,TOCOL(A2:A,1), end,TODAY(), start,end-560,
   calc,LAMBDA(c, INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE(
   c, "price", start, end, "weekly"),1,0),,2)),
   idx,calc("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50"),
   BYROW(range, LAMBDA(s, LET(
     avs,TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(calc("NSE:"& s)/idx),2),
     rw,SEQUENCE(ROWS(avs)),
     MAP(SEQUENCE(1,8,0), LAMBDA(s, LET(
       col,FILTER(avs, rw<53+s, rw>s),
       (INDEX(col,1)/AVERAGE(col)-1)*10)))))))
```

## Demo Spreadsheet

**[Link to editable spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IC1S3UsWnMNFLpfPIFemogBA4l_aiT0KGBLC6ourRtM/edit)**

Demo sheet includes added formula modifiers that illustrate approaches to   help reduce recalculation times:

1. **G6** (checkbox) 
    Enable/Disable calculation
2. **L6** (dropdown)
    Set the number of 52-week periods
3. **G7** (checkbox) 
    Limit stocks by column B checkbox
4. **K7 & L7** (checkbox & #)
    Limit max # stocks returned (works with or without **G7**)

[image]